# Can I get Touch input from a GUI Button?

Tags: user-interface, button, unity-game-engine

Can I touch GUI button on touch screen. In my script, I write this code for button click with unity c# script on Unity3d game engine.

```
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(100,100, 300,300),"ok",style) {
     //do stuff
}
```

When I use mouse click, it makes actions but on the touch screen, it is not work. I want to use it with both mouse click and touch on button. So can you advice how to make it?

Comment: Are you testing touch on Unity remote?

Comment: yes, unity remote installed on my android smart phone

Comment: There are a lot of known issues in Unity remote for android! I'll add an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Unity Remote` is Restrictions tool... 
you run project in Unity Editor. because, `GUI.Button()` event only pass mouse click event.
Best way. Try using **Bulid&Run** option. :D

Answer (score 0):

Unity `GUI.Button()` do support touch inputs. You do not need a separate implementation but there are some glitches in the **Unity Remote**. Best is to test it on the device straightaway.